# DialogBox not displaying

Tags: java, android, button, toast, dialog

When the save `button` clicked, I want it display a dialog box, which has `ok` and `cancel` `button` for confirmation. If `ok` `button` is clicked, data will be inserted follow by "Data Saved" message. If `cancel`, it will dismiss.

I try working out with sample code, but when I click on `save` `button`, the app crashed without showing any logcat error..how can I fix this?

**WorkDetailsTable.java**

```
 Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setTitle("Data Saved");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ii) {
                        W1 = txtWork1.getText().toString();
                        W2 = txtWork2.getText().toString();
                        W3 = txtWork3.getText().toString();
                        W4 = txtWork4.getText().toString();
                        a1 = spinnerTra.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        a2 = spinnerTra2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        a3 = spinnerTra3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        a4 = spinnerTra4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        P1 = per1.getText().toString();
                        P2 = per2.getText().toString();
                        P3 = per3.getText().toString();
                        P4 = per4.getText().toString();
                        long ab = ts.insertTimeSheet(name, weather,date,status);
                        WF.insertWorkForce(subContractors, noPeople, noHours);
                        WD.insertWorkDetails(a1, W1, P1, b, c, th, ab);
                        WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, W2, P2, d, e1, th, ab);
                        WD.insertWorkDetails(a3, W3, P3, f, g, th, ab);
                        WD.insertWorkDetails(a4,W4,P4,h,i,th,ab);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }

                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int ii)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
               builder.show();


            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace this line:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

with this one:

`AlertDialog builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this).create();`

Comment: Builder(android.content.Contex) in Builder cannot be applied

Comment: Sorry my bad. Is WorkDetailsTable.java extending activity?

Comment: Ya..public class WorkDetailsTable extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: Incompitable type...required "import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder", found"import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;".. When I import import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder, it saids unused statement.

Comment: Edited again, you need to create an AlertDialog object not an AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Error:(147, 24) error: cannot find symbol method setPositiveButton(String,<anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener>)

Comment: It works after I change to    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkDetailsTable.this); Thanks God :)